# Как узнать какой метод вызвал текущий метод

Tags: java

У меня есть в классе ONE два метода А и С, каждый передает свою уникальную строку в метод B, находящийся в классе TWO.

Метод B отправляет строку как sql запрос и возвращает результат.

И мне нужно понимать какой метод А или С прислал строку, от этот будет меняться логика работы метода В.

Как узнать какой метод вызвал текущий метод?

Comment: Если строки уникальные, то в чем проблема?

Comment: Понял, не верно задал вопрос. Не суть уникальная ли строка, есть ли приемы в java узнать какой метод вызвал текущий?

Comment: Приемы есть - вместе со строкой передать идентификатор вызывающего метода.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно получить текущий stacktrace и взять из него нужный элемент:

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
System.out.println(stackTrace[2].getMethodName());
```

Для полного примера

```
public class ONE
{
    public static void A()
    {
        TWO.B();
    }

    public static void C()
    {
        TWO.B();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class TWO
{
    public static void B()
    {
        StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        System.out.println(stackTrace[2].getMethodName());
    }
}
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ONE.A();
    ONE.C();
}
```

Вывод:

> A
>   C

Comment: очень круто, спасибо